# Codomain extension?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, manifolds

Suppose I am given a function $f:A\to B$, where both $A$ and $B$ are open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ (or for that matter, of any vector space $V$).

> Can I, without loss of generality, view $f$ as having codomain $\mathbb{R}$?

There are many reasons for this question:

1. If the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ then I can add functions pointwise and have a vector space structure on the space of functions. If however the codomain is **not** a vector space, I cannot possibly add the functions pointwise.
2. This question comes from the definition of a manifold, where I have charts $h_i:U_i \to h_i(U_i)$, and there is a *homeomorphism* between the open set $U_i\subset M$ ($M$ is a differentiable manifold) and $h_i(U_i)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I was wondering if I could view $h_i:U_i \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so that for example I can perform linear transformations on the $h_i$'s.
3. Lastly, the definition of the differential:

   A function $F:A\to W$, with $A$ open set of a normed linear space $V$ and $W$ a normed linear space is called differentiable at $a$ if there exists $T\in Hom(V,W)$ such that $\Delta_aF(x)=T(x)+\mathcal{o}$.

This definition considers only functions with codomain a vector space, what about the case where the codomain is also an open set, i.e., not a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the range of the function,i.e. its image $Im(f)$ has no vectorspace structure, but is contained in a normed linear space $W$ (like for example $\mathbb{R^n}$ as in the case of charts of an $n$-dimensional manifold) You can choose the codomain to be this normed linear space and consider the function $$f:A\rightarrow W$$
that might be not surjective and call it $f$ again. The set of functions with pointwise operation inherits the vector space structure, You can perform linear transformation on charts and the definition of the differential still makes sense. There is no need to assume that the range of the function has a vector space structure. It is sufficient that it is contained in some normed linear space.

Comment: Does this have to do with the fact that we can always construct the vector space generated by $Im f$, and this pressumably is always the normed linear space on which $Im f$ is contained?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is absolutely sufficient for Your purposes. The range doesn´t have to be endowed with a vector space structure itself

Comment: While at this, can there be an open set **not** contained in a vector space? If not then it seems to me, we can make any function have codomain a vector space, at the expense of not having it necessarily surjective...

Comment: Or may be we should ask "Can there be an open set $A$ in a topological space $X$ that is $\textbf{not}$ contained (or embedded) in a normed vector space $Y$ so that the relative  topology on $A$ induced by that of $X$ is equivalent to the relative topology induced by that of $Y$ which is induced by the norm on $Y$?"